# PythonMagick: Convert RGB to Grayscale

Tags: python, grayscale, pythonmagick

I found this description [link_1](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/Magick++/classMagick_1_1Image.html#ac3f118266e529bee3943d2043693bd33.), [link_2](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/MagickCore/colorspace_8h.html#a5d516b430fa42c1f83b557f08128f3c2).

Trying to do so

```
import PythonMagick
img = PythonMagick.Image('file.png')
img.colorSpace('GRAYColorspace')
```

Return this

```
ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    Image.colorSpace(Image, str)
did not match C++ signature:
    colorSpace(class Magick::Image {lvalue})
    colorSpace(class Magick::Image {lvalue}, enum MagickCore::ColorspaceType)
```

How to do it?

Comment: I may be wrong but I think PythonMagick project has been dead for more, than a couple of years. For image manipulation is better to use PIL or Pillow http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: I need to draw a circle, arc and other elements with a thickness of more than 1. PIL do not know how to

Answer (score 0):

PythonMagick already supports ColorSpaceTypes since version 9.10

http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=25229

Here's an example to accomplish what you're trying to do:

```
import PythonMagick as pm
img = pm.Image('file.png')
img.colorSpace(pm.ColorspaceType.GRAYColorspace)
```